# Does the @staticmethod decorator do anything?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made these two classes:

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def f(x):
        print("x is", x)

class B:
    def f(x):
        print("x is", x)
```

And used them like this:

```
>>> A.f(1)
x is 1
>>> B.f(1)
x is 1
```

It looks like `f` became a static method on B even without the decorator. Why would I need the decorator?

Comment: IMO, `staticmethod` provides very little utility. The thing it does is let you do is call it from an *instance of the class* as well as from the class. So try doing `B().f(1)` and `A().f(1)`. I'm pretty sure it's only there for people coming from languages like Java that force you to write class definitions for everything. I would pretty much always just use a stand-alone function instead of a staticmethod

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It used to matter more back in Python 2, where the instance-ness of instance methods was enforced more strongly:

```
>>> class B:
...     def f(x):
...         print("x is", x)
...
>>> B.f(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method f() must be called with B instance as first argument (
got int instance instead)
```

You *had* to mark static methods with `@staticmethod` back then.

These days, `@staticmethod` still makes it clearer that the method is static, which helps with code readability and documentation generation, and it lets you call the method on instances without the system trying to bind `self`.

Answer (score 3):

Try these two classes, both having a `cry` method, one as a classmethod and another as a staticmethod with `self` passed on

```
class Cat:

    def __init__(self):
        self.sound = "meow"

    def cry(self):
        print(self.sound)

x = Cat()
x.cry()
meow
```

and with another class

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sound = "ruff-ruff"

    @staticmethod
    def cry(self):
        print(self.sound)

x = Dog()
x.cry()
TypeError: cry() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

and we can see the `@staticmethod` decorator basically removed the passed in `self`

Comment: In other words: The `@staticmethod` decorator allows calling the static method using the dot operator on an object instance.

Comment: The first example is not a `classmethod` though, which is yet another decorator that marks the function to receive a reference to the class rather than a reference to the instance, in its first positional parameter. So no decorator: it's a method, and it receives a reference to the instance (some call it `self`); `classmethod` decorator: receives a reference to the class (some call it `cls`); `staticmethod` decorator: the function receives no references.